# How to batch update multiple Azure DevOps Work Items with one request via the Rest API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

The [documentation shows how to update a single work item via the Azure DevOps (Server) Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), but in the past, using the TFS client object model, one could send batch update / save requests to the TFS system that contained more than one work item.

Is this still possible with the Rest API and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to use the SDK which is into the NuGet package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client so not rely directly on the Rest API as that is a wrapper of the API.

If you search for examples in order to use that SDK you can find them here,
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples

The method that I am using it is into the WorkItemTrackingHttpClient class method client.ExecuteBatchRequest(my list of requests);